# simple Jquery code issue

Tags: jquery

When executing this code for the first time the page jumps to top, then work fine from second hover on other elments!

jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/FXhLz/

but the problem not obvious here i think because there is no page scroll

Comment: What do you mean by second time? Second hover? Second visit? Also have you separated the issue enough for us and you are sure CSS styles play no significant role in this case?

Comment: can you please add the CSS styles in the code sample as well?

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass` take only one parameters the class name or a function

Comment: css added
@Tadeck imean by second time , the hover on other element".more" in same page, and rest of elements play good after that.
 second hover for same element stuck and do no effect just toggle class.

Comment: @DoubleYo i removed it and issue resists

Comment: post a link to the page maybe? it's hard to picture out what you're trying to say.

Comment: Can you provide the Html for your code you asking question about?

Comment: its on local host
@cpoDesign html added

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine if you remove the `stop()` function as below, I guess the reason why your div was struck on further animation was when you use the slide effect it manipulates the elements height dynamically to acheive the animation and when you use the stop function and hover over when it is sliding down it is fixing the elemet at the height it was when it stopped hence on further animations you see it as struck, I guess its a jQuery bug.

```
$(function() {
  $(".more").hover(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.details_box', this).slideToggle(500);
    $(this).addClass('act');
  },
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.details_box', this).slideToggle(200);
        $(this).removeClass('act');
  });
});
```